# SmackAndroid(context) not found user search module ejabberd

Tags: android, chat, smack, ejabberd-module

I am working upon a android based chat application using ejabberd-17.01 server on windows. Using Smack 4.1 for android. I want to search for users using following code

```
public void searchUser(){
    try {
        UserSearchManager userSearchManager = new UserSearchManager(connection);
        Collection<String> services = userSearchManager.getSearchServices();
        if(services.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        Form searchForm = userSearchManager.getSearchForm(services.iterator().next());
        Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
        answerForm.setAnswer("Name", true);
        answerForm.setAnswer("search", "test"); // here i'm passsing the Text value to search

        ReportedData resultData;
        resultData = userSearchManager.getSearchResults(answerForm, "search." + connection.getServiceName());

        Iterator<ReportedData.Row> it = (Iterator)resultData.getRows();
        ReportedData.Row row = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String value = it.next().toString();
            Log.i("Iteartor values......", " " + value);
            System.out.println("Jabber_id :" + row.getValues("jid").toString());
            System.out.println("Name :" + row.getValues("Name").toString());
            row = it.next();
        }
    }
    catch (SmackException.NoResponseException | SmackException.NotConnectedException | XMPPException.XMPPErrorException | XmppStringprepException e){
        Log.w("app" , e.toString());
    }
}
```

my problem is that
userSearchManager.getSearchServices()
returns zero values. I read about that i should initialize smack for android by calling SmackAndroid.init(context) before connection but whenever i write this it only says create class SmackAndroid(context) and does not show any import.

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0"
```

i also tested all dependencies mentioned in smack document but cant find this method. What am i missing or is there any other way to search register user in ejabberd. Also i want to know do i need to add any module to ejabberd for searching purpose like search module is added manually in openfire server?